# Filtering by checking if list contains elements of other list. How to do that?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I can't figure out how to correctly create the first `return`. It would work like this but the problem is `searchtestarrayone` always has a different length and it can be pretty large. Started my journey with Swift a few weeks ago, so there might be stupid things in the code below and the answer can be obvious, forgive me.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController){

   if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text, !searchText.isEmpty {          
       transformSearchResult()

       filteredBusStopsArray = busStopsArray.filter { (busstop : BusStop)  in

           if !searchtestarrayone.isEmpty{
              return busstop.stopName.lowercased().contains(searchtestarrayone[0]) || busstop.stopName.lowercased().contains(searchtestarrayone[1])
           }
           else{
               return  busstop.stopName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
           }
```

Looking for some tips. Best regards.

Comment: What is the role of the `searchtestarrayone`?

Comment: It's array that contains combinations of letters in words, For example when you type in searchbar "aa" array will be filled with "aa", "aą", "ąa", "ąą". In general this is supposed to improve searching polish words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return whether `busstop.stopName` contains any of the values of `searchtestarrayone`'s values, you can use `contains.where`.

```
if !searchtestarrayone.isEmpty{
    return searchTestArrayOne.contains(where: {busStop.stopName.lowercased().contains($0)})
}
```

This will return true if any of the elements of `searchTestArrayOne` are contained in `busStop.stopName` and false otherwise. `contains(where:)` also exits early, as soon as it finds the first element matching the closure, so he full search array is only iterated through if there is no match.

Please also make sure that you conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lower-camelCase for function and variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You should map `busStopsArray` to only include lowercased stop names and  filter it with `searchtestarrayone`.

```
filteredBusStopsArray = (busStopsArray.map { $0.stopName.lowercased() }).filter {
    searchtestarrayone.contains($0)
}
```